# how to set the position of glasspane in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, glasspane

I'm trying to create a menu slider from the left side of the frame.
It need to be floating above the content, where i can access it always with a mouse listener(open the menu when the mouse is close to the left edge).

Well, I set my GlassPane (My JPanel ) as setOpaue(false) and it was floating above the content.
but the glasspane always positioned on the center, and I need to have a possibility to move it,slide it, but with no luck.

the setBounds and setLocation does not worked for me.

Can any one please help me with this ?

Part of Code :

```
   public class MYFrame extends JFrame {


        public MYFrame(){
                this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                this.add(panel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
                this.add(panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                this.add(panel3,BorderLayout.EAST);
                this.getRootPane().setGlassPane(new MyGlass());
                this.getRootPane().getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                this.setVisible(true);

             }


      public class MyGlass extends JPanel{
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("BG.png");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);

        public MyGlass(){
          this.add(label);
          this.setOpaque(false);
          this.pack();
          this.setVisible(true);
        }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `glassPane` will always cover the entire viewable area (content) of the window, this is how it's designed.

What you will want to do is, instead, add your `MyGlass` panel to the frame's `glassPane`.  This will, at least, provide you with control to move it.

Now, having said, I would recommend having a look at

- [java-universal-tween-engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)
- [sliding-layout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout)

And see if it helps.

As a wild proof of concept...

[image: Slide]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.setGlassPane(new GlassPane());
                frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            try {
                add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("....jpg")))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public class GlassPane extends JPanel {

        private MenuPane menuPane;

        public GlassPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            menuPane = new MenuPane();
            add(menuPane);
            setLayout(new SlidingMenuLayoutManager());

            menuPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    ((SlidingMenuLayoutManager)getLayout()).open();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    ((SlidingMenuLayoutManager)getLayout()).close();
                }

            });
        }

        protected class SlidingMenuLayoutManager implements LayoutManager {

            private int offSet = 10;
            private int delta = 2;
            private Timer slider;

            public SlidingMenuLayoutManager() {
                slider = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("...");
                        offSet += delta;
                        if (offSet <= 10) {
                            offSet = 10;
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                        } else if (offSet >= menuPane.getWidth()) {
                            offSet = menuPane.getWidth();
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                        }
                        menuPane.getParent().revalidate();
                        menuPane.getParent().repaint();
                    }
                });
            }

            public void open() {
                slider.stop();
                delta = 2;
                slider.start();
            }

            public void close() {
                slider.stop();
                delta = -2;
                slider.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
            }

            @Override
            public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
                Dimension size = menuPane.getPreferredSize();
                size.width *= 2;
                return size;
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
                return preferredLayoutSize(parent);
            }

            @Override
            public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
                Dimension size = menuPane.getPreferredSize();
                size.height = parent.getHeight();
                menuPane.setSize(size);

                int maxWidth = size.width;
                int xPos = offSet - maxWidth;
                menuPane.setLocation(xPos, 0);
            }

        }

    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public MenuPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 255, 128));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: first, thank you for your detailed answer. but I want to create a real menu with button inside it. and i dont know how i can paintComponent(g) of a buttons.

Comment: What do you mean ? You just have to add buttons to the `MenuPane` and manage them as usual...

Comment: The MenuPane is just a JPanel, I just made it transparent to prove the point, you don't need the paintComponent method (or should change the opacity state as well)