# How to create moving panels? Is it possible in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I know I can change panels by using card layout but while I was browsing I saw an effect where panels move from left or right to replace the current panel.
With Card Layout, changing panel is working but can't achieve a moving panel effect.

I don't know what it's called. I don't know if "dynamic" is the correct term for it.

So here's the link to help you guys understand my question better.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Y7cxgX4Suc

According to the description it's all done in Swing and no JavaFX.

Comment: There are many other layout managers other than card layout in java. Your animation can be achieved using MigLayout or GroupLayout.

Comment: There are lots of possible ways you could achieve it using a verity of techniques, for [example, SlidingLayout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668955/how-to-set-the-position-of-glasspane-in-jframe/28669000#28669000), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316132/animate-jpanel-slide-in-with-timer/16316345#16316345), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083355/jpanel-setlocation/19083537#19083537)

Comment: You could even wrap layout managers in an animated proxy, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368190/too-many-jpanels-inside-a-jpanel-with-gridbaglayout/32372506#32372506) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368190/too-many-jpanels-inside-a-jpanel-with-gridbaglayout/32372506#32372506) or just do some party tricks [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645202/set-jbutton-to-the-location-of-another-jbutton/29651705#29651705)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you so much for the suggestion. You've always provided very helpful and useful answers. Those options you included will help me decide which to add on my project. Thanks again.