# JPanel not turning visible when PopUp is fully expanded

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, graphics2d

I have a PopUp class that expands and contracts like a pop-up. It extends JPanel.

I have overridden the typical visibility methods for the JPanel to choose whether the PopUp object should be drawn. The JPanel should be visible only when the pop-up is fully expanded.

However, this is the part that does not work.

Here is the relevant PopUp class code. I added some comments that hopefully help:

```
public class PopUp extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Expanded x coordinate
     */
    private double x;
    /**
     * Expanded y coordinate
     */
    private double y;
    /**
     * Expanded width value
     */
    private double width;
    /**
     * Expanded height value
     */
    private double height;

    /**
     * Number of steps until fully expanded
     */
    private int steps;
    /**
     * This divided by steps is the percentage the pop-up is expanded
     */
    private int expansionStage = 0;

    /**
     * Whether or not the pop-up is expanding
     */
    private boolean isExpanding = false;
    /**
     * Whether or not the pop-up is visible
     */
    private boolean visible;

    /**
     * Color of the pop-up
     */
    private Color color;

    /**
     * The rectangle that represents the bounds of the pop-up
     */
    private Rectangle2D popUp;

    /**
     * The currently used transform for the pop-up
     */
    private AffineTransform trans;

    /**
     * Initializes a newly created {@code PopUp} with a uniform color
     * @param x                 The x coordinate of the expanded pop-up
     * @param y                 The y coordinate of the expanded pop-up
     * @param w                 The width of the expanded pop-up
     * @param h                 The height of the expanded pop-up
     * @param expansionSteps    The number of steps until fully expanded
     * @param popUpColor        The color of the pop-up
     */
    public PopUp(double x, double y, double w, double h, int expansionSteps, Color popUpColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        color = popUpColor;
        steps = expansionSteps;
        this.borderWidth = 0;
        this.borderColor = null;
        popUp = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
        setBounds((int) Math.round(x), (int) Math.round(y), (int) Math.round(w), (int) Math.round(h));
        trans = new AffineTransform();
        //Centers the rectangle pop-up at the center of the given rectangle made by the given x, y, width, and height
        trans.translate(x + width/2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage/steps), y + height/2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage/steps));
        //Scales the rectangle based on the percentage it is expanded
        trans.scale((double) expansionStage/steps, (double) expansionStage/steps);
    }

    /**
     * Draws the pop-up
     * @param g     Graphics object from paintComponent
     */
    public final void draw(Graphics g) {
        //Expands pop-up one step
        if(isExpanding && visible)
            expansionStage = Math.min(expansionStage + 1, steps);
        //Contracts pop-up one step
        else if(visible)
            expansionStage = Math.max(expansionStage - 1, 0);
        //Resets pop-up size to 0
        else
            expansionStage = 0;
        if(visible) {
            //Sets the visibility of the JPanel to true if the pop-up is fully expanded (false otherwise)
            super.setVisible(expansionStage/steps == 1);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
            //Centers the rectangle pop-up at the center of the given rectangle made by the given x, y, width, and height
            trans.translate(x + width/2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage/steps), y + height/2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage/steps));
            //Scales the rectangle based on the percentage it is expanded
            trans.scale((double) expansionStage/steps, (double) expansionStage/steps);
            this.trans = trans;
            g2d.setColor(color);
            Shape transformed = trans.createTransformedShape(popUp);
            g2d.fill(transformed);
        }
        else
            super.setVisible(false);
    }

    /**
     * Sets whether the pop-up is expanding or not
     * @param expanding    Whether or not the pop-up should expand
     */
    public final void setExpanding(boolean expanding) {
        isExpanding = expanding;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the pop-up is expanding
     * @return Whether or not the pop-up is expanding
     */
    public final boolean getExpanding() {
        return isExpanding;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the percentage that the pop-up has expanded
     * @return The percentage that the pop-up has expanded
     */
    public final double percentageExpanded() {
        return (double) expansionStage/steps;
    }

    /**
     * Different than JPanel.setVisible(boolean visible) in that it
     * only draws the PopUp if this is true, and the JPanel is visible
     * only when this is true and the popUp is expanded
     * @param visible   Whether or not the pop-up should be visible
     */
    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    /**
     * Different than JPanel.isVisible() in that it
     * only draws the PopUp if this is true, and the JPanel is visible
     * only when this is true and the popUp is expanded
     * @return  Whether or not the pop-up should be visible
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public boolean jPanelIsVisible() {
        return super.isVisible();
    }

}
```

I set it up by creating one. Then, I then add it to the main JPanel and set its visibility to true.

In the paintComponent() method for the main JPanel, I put a call to PopUp.draw(g).

Finally, I have PopUp.setExpanding(true) when I want it to expand and PopUp.setExpanding(false) when I want it to contract.

Let me know if any other information is required.

**Update:**

I am planning to use a modified version of MadProgrammer's version of my PopUp class, but I thought I would let you all know what the real problem was.

MadProgrammer had the right idea when he was thinking the visibility was the problem. When I was using super.setVisible(), it referred to my isVisible() method for my PopUp, which was unfortunate.

Comment: *"In the paintComponent() method for the main JPanel, I put a call to PopUp.draw(g)."* - Why? While would you need a panel to paint another panel, to me, this doesn't make sense and is counter intuitive of how a panel actually works

Comment: Over the years, I've developer a number of "popup" style APIs, some used plain old Windows (I wouldn't recommend it), but most relied heavily on the use of the `GlassPane`, as it provides a overlap layer over the top of the reset of the UI. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668955/how-to-set-the-position-of-glasspane-in-jframe/28669000#28669000), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473308/display-a-message-on-the-screen/26474379#26474379)

Comment: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961472/how-can-i-paint-in-an-specific-jpanel-when-more-than-one-in-same-frame-java/15961655#15961655) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083355/jpanel-setlocation/19083537#19083537). I even wrote a "message box" popup API for the express purpose of displaying short lived messages to the user, which was fully animated, allowed for automatic, manual and/or program dismissal. It also allowed for expansion for new message types of over time and was very comprehensive. It all used the `GlassPane` as the primary display surface

Comment: I have repaint() called for the main JPanel by a timer every 10 ms. I use the same graphics context for any drawing that I do. Based on what you said, It seems I am not drawing in an efficient way. So, I will try and remedy that for the next project I do. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's pretty cool! And I will definitely look at your classes. However, I feel like the PopUp class is nearly complete and just has the one minor aforementioned error. So, if possible, I would like to stick to this class at least for this project if you don't mind. :)

Comment: *"I have repaint() called for the main JPanel by a timer every 10 ms"* - Okay, is probably slightly incorrect. The `Timer` should be used to change the state of the `Popup` which should then trigger a paint cycle.  This makes the painting process independent of the update process, as painting can occur for any number of reasons

Comment: You "key" problem seems to be `super.setVisible(expansionStage/steps == 1);`, which is setting the visible state to `false` when `expansionStage/steps` is NOT equal to `1` - I'd also be concerned with extending from `JPanel`, as it's not providing any additional functionality and the animation should centred around the component itself, as it needs to decide when to start and stop it

Comment: @MadProgrammer The painting and updating should be separate. Got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some digging around, I think you biggest issue is with the "visibility" concept.

Namely, `super.setVisible(expansionStage/steps == 1);`, which will make the component invisible while `expansionStage/steps` is not equal to `1`.

I scrapped the concept of visibility and removed the inheritance from `JPanel`, as it's not adding any benefit and causing no end of issues.

I also moved the animation cycle to the class itself and used a `update` method to update the state independently of the paint process, as painting can occur at any time for any number of reasons, which could interrupt with the animation.

I also added a couple of methods which provide information about whether the class is fully expanded or collapsed, which provides a trigger point for determining when the animation should be stopped.

In my mind (scary place), you should have a "state" variable which contains `expanded`, `collapsed`, `expanding` and `collapsing`, from which you can make determinations about what should occur at different times.  It also means you could reverse the animation mid cycle if you wanted to.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private PopUp popUp;

        public TestPane() {
            popUp = new PopUp(10, 10, 180, 180, 10, Color.yellow);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    popUp.animate(TestPane.this);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            popUp.draw(g);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class PopUp {

        /**
         * Expanded x coordinate
         */
        private double x;
        /**
         * Expanded y coordinate
         */
        private double y;
        /**
         * Expanded width value
         */
        private double width;
        /**
         * Expanded height value
         */
        private double height;

        /**
         * Number of steps until fully expanded
         */
        private int steps;
        /**
         * This divided by steps is the percentage the pop-up is expanded
         */
        private int expansionStage = 0;

        /**
         * Whether or not the pop-up is expanding
         */
        private boolean isExpanding = false;
        /**
         * Whether or not the pop-up is visible
         */
//      private boolean visible;

        /**
         * Color of the pop-up
         */
        private Color color;

        /**
         * The rectangle that represents the bounds of the pop-up
         */
        private Rectangle2D popUp;

        /**
         * The currently used transform for the pop-up
         */
        private AffineTransform trans;

        private Timer timer;
        private Component parent;

        /**
         * Initializes a newly created {@code PopUp} with a uniform color
         *
         * @param x The x coordinate of the expanded pop-up
         * @param y The y coordinate of the expanded pop-up
         * @param w The width of the expanded pop-up
         * @param h The height of the expanded pop-up
         * @param expansionSteps The number of steps until fully expanded
         * @param popUpColor The color of the pop-up
         */
        public PopUp(double x, double y, double w, double h, int expansionSteps, Color popUpColor) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            width = w;
            height = h;
            color = popUpColor;
            steps = expansionSteps;
//          this.borderWidth = 0;
//          this.borderColor = null;
            popUp = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
//          setBounds((int) Math.round(x), (int) Math.round(y), (int) Math.round(w), (int) Math.round(h));
            trans = new AffineTransform();
            //Centers the rectangle pop-up at the center of the given rectangle made by the given x, y, width, and height
            trans.translate(x + width / 2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage / steps), y + height / 2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage / steps));
            //Scales the rectangle based on the percentage it is expanded
            trans.scale((double) expansionStage / steps, (double) expansionStage / steps);

            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    update();
                    parent.repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public void animate(Component parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
            setExpanding(isCollapsed());
            timer.start();
        }

        public void update() {
            //Expands pop-up one step
            if (isExpanding) {
                if (!isExpanded()) {
                    expansionStage = Math.min(expansionStage + 1, steps);
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            } //Contracts pop-up one step
            else {
                if (!isCollapsed()) {
                    expansionStage = Math.max(expansionStage - 1, 0);
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isCollapsed() {
            return (((double) expansionStage / (double) steps) == 0);
        }

        public boolean isExpanded() {
            return (((double) expansionStage / (double) steps) == 1);
        }

        /**
         * Draws the pop-up
         *
         * @param g Graphics object from paintComponent
         */
        public final void draw(Graphics g) {
//          if (visible) {
            //Sets the visibility of the JPanel to true if the pop-up is fully expanded (false otherwise)

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
            //Centers the rectangle pop-up at the center of the given rectangle made by the given x, y, width, and height

            trans.translate(x + width / 2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage / steps), y + height / 2 * (1 - (double) expansionStage / steps));
            //Scales the rectangle based on the percentage it is expanded
            trans.scale((double) expansionStage / steps, (double) expansionStage / steps);
            this.trans = trans;
            g2d.setColor(color);
            Shape transformed = trans.createTransformedShape(popUp);
            g2d.fill(transformed);
//          } else {
////                setVisible(false);
//          }
        }

        /**
         * Sets whether the pop-up is expanding or not
         *
         * @param expanding Whether or not the pop-up should expand
         */
        public final void setExpanding(boolean expanding) {
            isExpanding = expanding;
//          setVisible(expanding);
        }

        /**
         * Returns whether or not the pop-up is expanding
         *
         * @return Whether or not the pop-up is expanding
         */
        public final boolean getExpanding() {
            return isExpanding;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the percentage that the pop-up has expanded
         *
         * @return The percentage that the pop-up has expanded
         */
        public final double percentageExpanded() {
            return (double) expansionStage / steps;
        }

//      /**
//       * Different than JPanel.setVisible(boolean visible) in that it only draws
//       * the PopUp if this is true, and the JPanel is visible only when this is
//       * true and the popUp is expanded
//       *
//       * @param visible Whether or not the pop-up should be visible
//       */
//      public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
//          this.visible = visible;
//      }
//
//      /**
//       * Different than JPanel.isVisible() in that it only draws the PopUp if this
//       * is true, and the JPanel is visible only when this is true and the popUp
//       * is expanded
//       *
//       * @return Whether or not the pop-up should be visible
//       */
//      public boolean isVisible() {
//          return visible;
//      }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll try this! However, my intention was actually to have the JPanel be invisible until the pop-up was fully expanded because I only wanted the JPanel to intercept mouse events when it was fully expanded. I'm sorry if I was unclear about this. (I removed the MouseListener stuff in an attempt to simplify.)

Comment: Okay so under the current implementation I have, I might consider putting into place a "expansion" listener, which provide notifications when it was fully expanded or collapsed, that we you could setup/take down the `MouseListener` in response to those events